# Dynamically set list object type in c#

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a List object that I need to be able to swap the object type dynamically. Basically I have:

```
List<DataBaseItems> items = new List<DataBaseItems>();
```

I will then perform some filtering on that list with LINQ then bind to a telerik grid. I need to swap out the object based on an id that i get. My goal is to build a custom control that can use it's filter button for multiple reports where the report data is coming from the above list. Report A may use the above list and report B needs a completely different object but has the same actions on it.

Comment: Use generics, **OR** add a common interface that is supported by all the objects you want to use in such a list/situation, and program against the interface instead of the concrete objects. **OR** use reflection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public interface ICustomListFilter<T> 
       where T:class
{
    public void FilterAndBindMyList(List<T> myList);
}

public class ReportOneFilter:ICustomListFilter<MyFirstType>
{
    public void FilterAndBindMyList(List<MyFirstType> items)
    {

        // your filtering and binding code goes here, such as items.Where(i => ...
    }
}

public class ReportTwoFilter:ICustomListFilter<MySecondType>
{
    public void FilterAndBindMyList(List<MySecondType> items)
    {

        // your another filtering and binding algorithm goes here, such as items.Select(i => ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an interface and implement it into whatever objects you implement.